# Bootstrap 4.1 long-text go under second col from first..How?

Tags: bootstrap-4, grid, col, longtext, horizontal-line

[image]Is there any way text goes under the second col..There is a free-space under it and i want text to take 100% width of the screen when is possible.I fixed height of secodnd col with height:fit-content..so there is space to grow first.. I`m searching long time to find an answear and find something simillar like this -> https://www.codeply.com/go/njEg31ZG33 ,but not work for me.Sorry for my bad English..

```
[![<div class='container-fluid>
    <div class='row>

<div class='col'>
...long text...
<div>

<div class='col-6'>
many nested col and rows...
</div>

</div>
</div>][1]][1]
```

full code ---->

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div  id='offer-module'>
  <div class="row collapse flex-row no-gutters" id='offer-collapse' aria-expanded="false"  >
    <div class="col-6  pr-3  ">

      <p>
        Ексклузивно Ви представяме този изключителен тристаен апартамент, завършен и обзаведен по дизайнерски проект,
        под наем за летен сезон, в престижната сграда Belle Époque Beach Residence, разположена на първа линия море и
        плаж в артистичния курорт Лозенец.
      </p>

      <p>
        Апартаментът се намира на втори етаж в основната секция "А", която разполага с асансьор и където е разположена
        рецепцията и лоби зоната на елитната морска резиденция. От апартамента се откриват прекрасни гледки към басейна
        и градината на комплекса, както и към морето и плажа. Жилището е използвано само 3 сезона от собствениците, за
        лична употреба, като летен имот и никога не е отдавано под наем.
      </p>

      <p>Имотът се предлага с всички мебели и оборудване.</p>

      <p>Жилището е с високи тавани 3.00 м светла височина. Апартаментът е с благоприятно изложение на изток при хола и
        родителската спалня, и на запад за детската спалня, която гледа към красиво оформена градина в съседство с
        резиденцията.</p>

      <p>Апартаментът разполага с 2 спални, хол с кухненски бокс, баня и тоалетна, тераса с изглед към морето.</p>

      <p>Жилището е напълно обзаведено и оборудвано с качествени мебели и техника от реномирани марки като Bosch и
        Samsung. Интериорът е изпълнен по проект на водещ столичен интериорен дизайнер. Цялата корпусна мебела, в т.ч. и
        кухнята са изпълнени по поръчка, от лакирани MDF плочи, в комбинация с боядисан MDF — дървесен растер. Меката
        мебел и леглата са от качествен производител, с матраци висок клас. Мебелите са подбирани с вкус и желание за
        представителност и максимален комфорт, подобаващо за имот за лично ползване.</p>

      <p class='mb-0'>
        Кухнята е изключително функционална, просторна и разполага с всички удобства и техника от вградени уреди,
        необходими за пълноценно готвене на домашна храна, в това число:</p>

      <p class='mb-0'>• Голям семеен хладилник (Bosch); </p>
      <p class='mb-0'> • Пералня (Bosch);</p>
      <p class='mb-0'>• Керамични котлони (Bosch); </p>
      <p class='mb-0'>• Абсорбатор; </p>
      <p class='mb-0'> • Фурна (Bosch);</p>
      <p class='mb-0'> • Мивка Blanco;</p>
      <p class='mb-0'> • Вградена мелница за органични отпадъци в мивката;</p>
      <p class='mb-0'>• Тостер, ел. чайник и кафе машина, всички с марката Saeco; </p>
      <p class='mb-0'>• Достатъчно работни плотове на кухнята; </p>
      <p> • Просторни шкафове за съхранение на всякаква посуда и прибори.</p>

      <p>Холната мебел е семпла, но красива, функционална и удобна за цялото семейство. Телевизорът в хола е от марката
        Samsung. Прозорците са покрити с тънки и дебели завеси "black out". </p>

      <p>Родителската спалня разполага с голямо двойно легло 180х200 см, с матрак от висок клас на Happy Dreams,
        дизайнерски нощни шкафчета и красива стояща лампа, както и голям поръчков гардероб до тавана. Прозорците са
        покрити със от сет тънки и дебели "black out" завеси, които гарантират абсолютно затъмняване на помещението.
        Плосък телевизор Samsung е инсталиран на стената.</p>

      <p>Детската спалня също разполага с двойно легло, но с размер 164х200 см, и също с матрак от висок клас на Happy
        Dreams, дизайнерски нощни шкафчета. Голям гардероб по поръчка е монтиран до тавана. Телевизор Samsung е
        инсталиран на стената.</p>

      <p>Коридорът разполага с голям шкаф за обувки, простиращ се до тавана, голямо огледало със закачалки и красива
        дървена пейка.</p>

      <p>Терасата е достатъчно просторна и разполага със столчета и масичка от ратан.</p>

      <p>Настилките във всички помещения са от естествен камък — мрамор, а банята е комбинация от мрамор Розалия, гранит
        Тан Браун и декоративна мазилка по интериорен проект. Подовата настилка на балкона е от плочки от естествена
        глина – Клинкер. Стените са предварително изшкурени и грундирани, след което са боядисани в светъл нюанс охра, с
        качествена латексова боя. Жилището разполага и с блиндирана входна врата в съответствие с всички жилища в
        резиденцията. Всички врати в жилището са от качествен MDF.</p>

      <p>При строителството на сградата са използвани висок клас материали, в това число всички външни и преградни стени
        са зидани с тухли Wienerberger, с висока шумоизолираност, с машинно поставена мазилка и гладка шпакловка. Всички
        стени в апартамента са тухлени - масивни, не е използван гипсокартон, освен на местата с ревизионни отвори.
        Прозорците на всички апартаменти в сградата са от от алуминиева Elvial дограма от реномирания производител
        Kristian Neiko, с подпрозоречни первази от естествен камък. Санитарията в банята е Grohe (вградена структура,
        батерии и душ). Тоалетна чиния и умивалник - Roca/Ideal Standard, електрически бойлер Ariston за топла вода,
        бързозагряващ, с вместимост 120 л., електрически вентилатор, свързан към отдушник. Зоната за къпане в банята
        разполага със стъклена преграда. Инсталирани са аксесоари в банята.</p>

      <p>
        Всяка стая на апартамента е оборудвана с висок клас инверторни климатици от реномираната марка Daikin, работещи
        в режим охлаждане през лятото и отопление през зимата (до минус 20 градуса).
      </p>

      <p>Всяко помещение разполага с изводи за Интернет и кабелна телевизия, към които са включени телевизорите и рутер
        за безжичен Интернет.</p>

      <p class='mb-0'>За сградата</p>
      <p>
        Резиденция Belle Époque в Лозенец, е една от най-красивите и елегантни жилищни сгради по българското Черноморие.
        Изградена в класически френски стил, с множество орнаменти по фасадата, нейният дизайн-проект е вдъхновен от
        архитектурата на емблематичните курорти по Лазурния бряг Ница, Кан и Сен Тропе. Идеята за построяването й е
        повлияна от забележителната елегантност и насладата от живота, характерни за края на 18-ти и началото на 19-ти
        век. "Belle Époque" или "Xубавото време" е период на разцвет на изкуствата, изпълнен с красота, безгрижие и
        разкош, който оставя завинаги носталгията по една прекрасна утопична хармония.
      </p>

      <p>
        Всеки орнамент на сградата, всеки малък детайл допринася за пълната хармония на облика й. Пищните корнизи,
        изящно извитите парапети от ковано желязо и перлената белота в съчетание с богато озеленяване пренасят
        обитателите в онзи изгубен рай на "Хубавото време", който съчетава романтика и блясък, лукс и безгрижие,
        изисканост и красота.
      </p>

      <p>
        Belle Époque Beach Residence представлява жилищна сграда на четири етажа с разгъната застроена площ 2236 кв.м. и
        само 36 апартамента, разпределени в 3 тела. В периметъра на сградата са разположение и 14 открити паркоместа.
        Разположена е на оградена територия с контролиран достъп само за собствениците и гости на резиденцията.
        Завършена през лятото на 2016 г., Резиденцията заема първа морска линия до красивия централен пясъчен плаж на
        Лозенец, недалеч от живописния скалист нос Амбелиц. В съседство се намират плажните заведения, ресторант Тарама
        и пиано бийч бар Camino. Централният плаж на Лозенец е един от 5-те плажа, намиращи се в пешеходна близост.
        Недалеч от резиденцията се намира малкият миден плаж Меча дупка, култовият плаж Корал, както и плажове Hacienda
        Beach и Oasis. Центърът на курорта Лозенец с неговите емблематични барове и ресторанти се намира само на 10
        минути пеша и до него се стига лесно по самия плаж или по плажната алея.
      </p>

      <p>
        Екстрите и удобствата в сградата включват голям басейн със зона за деца, зона с шезлонги и чадъри, рецепция с
        рецепционист през летните месеци, нощна охрана целогодишно, представително фоайе/лоби зона с луксозен интериор и
        мебели, паркинг, контролиран достъп, озеленена градина с различни растения, в това число палми.</p>

    </div>
    <div class="col-6 pl-3 height-fit   ">
      <div class="row no-gutters ">

        <div class="col-6 ">
          <div class="mr-2 bg-gray px-3 py-4 ">
          <div class="h6 font-weight-bold text-center mb-075 text-dark-pink">ХАРАКРЕТИСТИКИ НА ИМОТА</div>

          <div class="row no-gutters justify-content-between card-offer ">
            <div class="col-6 ">
              <p class="text-muted"> Тип: <span class='text-dark'>Четиристаен апартамент
                </span></p>
              <p class="text-muted"> Брой спални: <span class='text-dark'>3 (max. 6 човека)
                </span></p>
              <p class="text-muted"> Бани/WC:<span class='text-dark'> 2
                </span></p>
              <p class="text-muted"> Паркиране: <span class='text-dark'> 2
                </span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 mx-auto pl-3">
              <p class="text-muted"> Площ:<span class='text-dark'> 185 м<sup>2</sup>
                </span></p>
              <p class="text-muted"> Етаж:<span class='text-dark'> 4
                </span></p>
              <p class="text-muted">Тераси:<span class='text-dark'> 2
                </span></p>
              <p class="text-muted">Склад:<span class='text-dark'>няма
                </span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="h6 font-weight-bold  mb-075 mt-5 text-center">
                УДОБСТВА В ИМОТА</div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-6">Оборудвана кухня</div>
            <div class="col-6 pl-3">Сушилня</div>
            <div class="col-6">Пералня</div>
            <div class="col-6 pl-3">Съдомиялна</div>
            <div class="col-6">Хладилник</div>
            <div class="col-6 pl-3">Фризер</div>

            <div class="col-6">Микровълнова печка</div>
            <div class="col-6 pl-3">Фурна</div>
            <div class="col-6">Котлони</div>
            <div class="col-6 pl-3">Климатици</div>
            <div class="col-6">Собствено паркомясто или гараж</div>
            <div class="col-6 pl-3">Джакузи</div>
            <div class="col-6">Отопление на парно</div>
            <div class="col-6 pl-3">Парна баня</div>
            <div class="col-6">Аудио / видео система</div>
            <div class="col-6 pl-3">Телевизори</div>
            <div class="col-6">Подово отопление</div>
            <div class="col-6 pl-3">Паркет</div>
            <div class="col-6">Мокет</div>
            <div class="col-6 pl-3">Мраморен под</div>
            <div class="col-6">СОТ</div>
            <div class="col-6 pl-3">Wi-Fi интернет</div>
            <div class="col-6">Джакузи</div>

            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="h6 font-weight-bold   mb-075 mt-5 text-center">
                УДОБСТВА В ИМОТА</div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-6">Морски гледки</div>
            <div class="col-6 pl-3">Гледки към плаж</div>
            <div class="col-6">Гледки към басейн</div>
            <div class="col-6 pl-3">Гледки към вътрешен двор</div>

            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="h6 font-weight-bold  mb-075 mt-5 text-center">
                УДОБСТВА В ИМОТА</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
              Открит басейн в комплекса
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 pl-3">
              Закрит басейн в комплекса
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
              Детска площадка в комплекса
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 pl-3">
              Спа център в комплекса
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 ">
              Фитнес център в комплекса
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 pl-3">
              Тенис корт в комплекса
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 ">
              Ресторант в комплекса
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 pl-3">
              Игрище в комплекса
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 ">
          Затворен комплекс (собствена територия)
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 pl-3">
              Консиерж / рецепция  
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
              Бар в комплекса
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 pl-3">
              Охрана
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-6   card-offer ">
          <div class="ml-2 bg-dark-pink text-white px-3 py-4 h-100">
          <p class='card-price mb-075 font-weight-bold mb-0 text-center'>
            €150 нощувка/ <span>€1,200 седмица/</span> <span>€3,100 месец/</span> <span>€12,000 сезон</span> 
          </p>
          <div class="row no-gutters mb-4">
          <div class="col-12 font-thin"> Минимален период: 3 нощувки</div>
          <div class="col-12 font-thin">Максимален период: Неогрничено, целогодишно</div>
        </div>
        <div  class="col-12 btn-offers text-center">ЗАПИТВАНЕ / РЕЗЕРВАЦИЯ</div>
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="h6 font-weight-bold text-center mb-075 text-orange mt-5">
            НАЧИНИ НА ПЛАЩАНЕ</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-6">
          В брой в нашия офис 
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          По банков път
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          В кредитна/дебитна карта 
        </div>

        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="h6 font-weight-bold text-center mb-075 mt-5 text-purple">
            КАК ДА РЕЗЕРВИРАТЕ</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
          <span class="float-left pr-2" ><img  class="offer-icon" src="images/icons_badges/num-111.png" alt=""></span>
          <span class='font-weight-bold '>Изпратете запитване за желани от Вас дати</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 mt-3">
          <span class="float-left pr-2" ><img  class="offer-icon" src="images/icons_badges/num-222.png" alt=""></span>
          <span class='font-weight-bold '>Депозирате 20% от стойността на наема</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 mt-3">
          <span class="float-left pr-2" ><img  class="offer-icon" src="images/icons_badges/num-333.png" alt=""></span>
          <span class='font-weight-bold '>Плащате остатъка след настаняване в имота</span>
        </div>
      </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay-border-bottom"></div>
  </div>
  <a role="button" class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#offer-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
  </a>

</div>
</div>
```

CSS code ---->

```
.height-fit{
  height: fit-content!important;
}
    #offer-module #offer-collapse.collapse:not(.show) {
      height: 450px !important;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 100%;
      display: -webkit-box;
      -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    }
    #offer-module #offer-collapse.collapsing {
      height: 450px !important;
    }
    #offer-module a.collapsed:after {
      content: "\f078";
      font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
      color: $dark;
      font-size: 2rem;
    }
    #offer-module a {
      text-decoration: none;
      margin-left: 50%;
    }

    #offer-module a:not(.collapsed):after {
      content: "\f077";
      font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
      color: $dark;
      font-size: 2rem;
    }
    #offer-collapse.collapse:not(.show) {
      position: relative;
      & .overlay-border-bottom {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;

        width: 100%;
        height: 32px;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.63);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.63) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 99%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
        background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.63)), color-stop(99%, rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255,255,255,1)));
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.63) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 99%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.63) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 99%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.63) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 99%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0.63) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 99%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=0 );
      }
    }
```

Comment: can you provide the code so we can edit it based on your need!

Answer (score 1):

The image shown below is not possible, you can't make `col` with such behaviour

[image]

While the image shown below is possible

[image]

---

## Here is the code

You have to break the `col` from where the text has to be `100%`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>
 <div class="container-fluid p-3">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-6" style="background-color:cornflowerblue;">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut possimus repellendus provident, beatae excepturi dignissimos, similique quidem porro laborum quas quos harum nihil, eum nemo iusto enim nobis nulla obcaecati.Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut possimus repellendus provident, beatae excepturi dignissimos, similique quidem porro laborum quas quos harum nihil, eum nemo iusto enim nobis nulla obcaecati.Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut possimus repellendus provident, beatae excepturi dignissimos, similique quidem porro laborum quas quos harum nihil, eum nemo iusto enim nobis nulla obcaecati. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis, beatae ratione temporibus sint voluptatem expedita rerum incidunt impedit! Ex non reiciendis quae fugiat mollitia unde quia natus! In, possimus dignissimos? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum asperiores corporis libero eligendi vel, accusamus tenetur delectus similique cum, consectetur nostrum voluptatem commodi, debitis aliquid facere amet alias iusto obcaecati. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi nobis fugiat, ipsam optio delectus saepe rerum quisquam? Ratione cumque sint itaque, rerum voluptates numquam sit officia, magni, doloremque odio maiores! Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum nesciunt explicabo quas provident quibusdam perspiciatis nihil molestiae dolores facilis et assumenda itaque, suscipit modi laborum esse asperiores illo aliquam illum!</div>
     
     <div class="col-6 align-self-center text-center">
      <div class=" p-4 row">
        <div class="col" style="background-color:grey;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicinsegasgvsdgsegsegsv cx g elit. Dignissimos, velit? Quis ipsa laboriot vel sapssssssssssssssssiente quas non deserunt cupiditate, ipsum quia? Rem, voluptatibus? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecteturssssssssssssssssiente quas non deserunt cupiditatonsectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis fuga aperiam laborum porro maxime accusamus similique esse, illum impedit aut vel sapiente quas non deserunt cupiditate, ipsum quia? Rem, voluptatibus?</div>
        <div class="col" style="background-color: palevioletred;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
     
     <div class="col" style="background-color:cornflowerblue;">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, ex itaque illo mollitia blanditiis quibusdam nostrum qui consequuntur pariatur ducimus iste eum dolorem veritatis! Consectetur sed obcaecati cum quas hic.</div>
   </div>
 </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for response,but i don`t know where to break col..aspecially for different resolutions..I will try something with flex-box..

Comment: another way with script...:(

Answer (score 0):

[image]So finally found the solution with div wrapper with class CLEARFIX and float-right class to columns.Here is the full code solution ->

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div  id='offer-module'>
  <div class=" collapse  " id='offer-collapse' aria-expanded="false"  >


<div class="clearfix">
    <div class="second-col-offer height-fit  pl-3">
      <div class="row no-gutters ">

        <div class="col-6 ">
          <div class="mr-2 bg-gray px-3 py-4 ">
          <div class="h6 font-weight-bold text-center mb-075 text-dark-pink">ХАРАКРЕТИСТИКИ НА ИМОТА</div>

          <div class="row no-gutters justify-content-between card-offer ">
            <div class="col-6 ">
              <p class="text-muted"> Тип: <span class='text-dark'>Четиристаен апартамент
                </span></p>
              <p class="text-muted"> Брой спални: <span class='text-dark'>3 (max. 6 човека)
                </span></p>
              <p class="text-muted"> Бани/WC:<span class='text-dark'> 2
                </span></p>
              <p class="text-muted"> Паркиране: <span class='text-dark'> 2
                </span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 mx-auto pl-3">
              <p class="text-muted"> Площ:<span class='text-dark'> 185 м<sup>2</sup>
                </span></p>
              <p class="text-muted"> Етаж:<span class='text-dark'> 4
                </span></p>
              <p class="text-muted">Тераси:<span class='text-dark'> 2
                </span></p>
              <p class="text-muted">Склад:<span class='text-dark'>няма
                </span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="h6 font-weight-bold  mb-075 mt-5 text-center">
                УДОБСТВА В ИМОТА</div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-6">Оборудвана кухня</div>
            <div class="col-6 pl-3">Сушилня</div>
            <div class="col-6">Пералня</div>
            <div class="col-6 pl-3">Съдомиялна</div>
            <div class="col-6">Хладилник</div>
            <div class="col-6 pl-3">Фризер</div>

            <div class="col-6">Микровълнова печка</div>
            <div class="col-6 pl-3">Фурна</div>
            <div class="col-6">Котлони</div>
            <div class="col-6 pl-3">Климатици</div>
            <div class="col-6">Собствено паркомясто или гараж</div>
            <div class="col-6 pl-3">Джакузи</div>
            <div class="col-6">Отопление на парно</div>
            <div class="col-6 pl-3">Парна баня</div>
            <div class="col-6">Аудио / видео система</div>
            <div class="col-6 pl-3">Телевизори</div>
            <div class="col-6">Подово отопление</div>
            <div class="col-6 pl-3">Паркет</div>
            <div class="col-6">Мокет</div>
            <div class="col-6 pl-3">Мраморен под</div>
            <div class="col-6">СОТ</div>
            <div class="col-6 pl-3">Wi-Fi интернет</div>
            <div class="col-6">Джакузи</div>

            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="h6 font-weight-bold   mb-075 mt-5 text-center">
                УДОБСТВА В ИМОТА</div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-6">Морски гледки</div>
            <div class="col-6 pl-3">Гледки към плаж</div>
            <div class="col-6">Гледки към басейн</div>
            <div class="col-6 pl-3">Гледки към вътрешен двор</div>

            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="h6 font-weight-bold   mb-075 mt-5 text-center">
                УДОБСТВА В ИМОТА</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
              Открит басейн в комплекса
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 pl-3">
              Закрит басейн в комплекса
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
              Детска площадка в комплекса
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 pl-3">
              Спа център в комплекса
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 ">
              Фитнес център в комплекса
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 pl-3">
              Тенис корт в комплекса
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 ">
              Ресторант в комплекса
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 pl-3">
              Игрище в комплекса
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 ">
          Затворен комплекс (собствена територия)
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 pl-3">
              Консиерж / рецепция  
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
              Бар в комплекса
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 pl-3">
              Охрана
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-6   card-offer ">
          <div class="ml-2 bg-dark-pink text-white px-3 py-4 h-100">
          <p class='card-price mb-075 font-weight-bold mb-0 text-center'>
            €150 нощувка/ <span>€1,200 седмица/</span> <span>€3,100 месец/</span> <span>€12,000 сезон</span> 
          </p>
          <div class="row no-gutters mb-4">
          <div class="col-12 font-thin"> Минимален период: 3 нощувки</div>
          <div class="col-12 font-thin">Максимален период: Неогрничено, целогодишно</div>
        </div>
        <div  class="col-12 btn-offers text-center">ЗАПИТВАНЕ / РЕЗЕРВАЦИЯ</div>
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="h6 font-weight-bold text-center mb-075 text-orange mt-5">
            НАЧИНИ НА ПЛАЩАНЕ</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-6">
          В брой в нашия офис 
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          По банков път
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          В кредитна/дебитна карта 
        </div>

        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="h6 font-weight-bold text-center mb-075 mt-5 text-purple">
            КАК ДА РЕЗЕРВИРАТЕ</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
          <span class="float-left pr-2" ><img  class="offer-icon" src="images/icons_badges/num-111.png" alt=""></span>
          <span class='font-weight-bold '>Изпратете запитване за желани от Вас дати</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 mt-3">
          <span class="float-left pr-2" ><img  class="offer-icon" src="images/icons_badges/num-222.png" alt=""></span>
          <span class='font-weight-bold '>Депозирате 20% от стойността на наема</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 mt-3">
          <span class="float-left pr-2" ><img  class="offer-icon" src="images/icons_badges/num-333.png" alt=""></span>
          <span class='font-weight-bold '>Плащате остатъка след настаняване в имота</span>
        </div>
      </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>



      <p>
        Ексклузивно Ви представяме този изключителен тристаен апартамент, завършен и обзаведен по дизайнерски проект,
        под наем за летен сезон, в престижната сграда Belle Époque Beach Residence, разположена на първа линия море и
        плаж в артистичния курорт Лозенец.
      </p>

      <p>
        Апартаментът се намира на втори етаж в основната секция "А", която разполага с асансьор и където е разположена
        рецепцията и лоби зоната на елитната морска резиденция. От апартамента се откриват прекрасни гледки към басейна
        и градината на комплекса, както и към морето и плажа. Жилището е използвано само 3 сезона от собствениците, за
        лична употреба, като летен имот и никога не е отдавано под наем.
      </p>

      <p>Имотът се предлага с всички мебели и оборудване.</p>

      <p>Жилището е с високи тавани 3.00 м светла височина. Апартаментът е с благоприятно изложение на изток при хола и
        родителската спалня, и на запад за детската спалня, която гледа към красиво оформена градина в съседство с
        резиденцията.</p>

      <p>Апартаментът разполага с 2 спални, хол с кухненски бокс, баня и тоалетна, тераса с изглед към морето.</p>

      <p>Жилището е напълно обзаведено и оборудвано с качествени мебели и техника от реномирани марки като Bosch и
        Samsung. Интериорът е изпълнен по проект на водещ столичен интериорен дизайнер. Цялата корпусна мебела, в т.ч. и
        кухнята са изпълнени по поръчка, от лакирани MDF плочи, в комбинация с боядисан MDF — дървесен растер. Меката
        мебел и леглата са от качествен производител, с матраци висок клас. Мебелите са подбирани с вкус и желание за
        представителност и максимален комфорт, подобаващо за имот за лично ползване.</p>

      <p class='mb-0'>
        Кухнята е изключително функционална, просторна и разполага с всички удобства и техника от вградени уреди,
        необходими за пълноценно готвене на домашна храна, в това число:</p>

      <p class='mb-0'>• Голям семеен хладилник (Bosch); </p>
      <p class='mb-0'> • Пералня (Bosch);</p>
      <p class='mb-0'>• Керамични котлони (Bosch); </p>
      <p class='mb-0'>• Абсорбатор; </p>
      <p class='mb-0'> • Фурна (Bosch);</p>
      <p class='mb-0'> • Мивка Blanco;</p>
      <p class='mb-0'> • Вградена мелница за органични отпадъци в мивката;</p>
      <p class='mb-0'>• Тостер, ел. чайник и кафе машина, всички с марката Saeco; </p>
      <p class='mb-0'>• Достатъчно работни плотове на кухнята; </p>
      <p> • Просторни шкафове за съхранение на всякаква посуда и прибори.</p>

      <p>Холната мебел е семпла, но красива, функционална и удобна за цялото семейство. Телевизорът в хола е от марката
        Samsung. Прозорците са покрити с тънки и дебели завеси "black out". </p>

      <p>Родителската спалня разполага с голямо двойно легло 180х200 см, с матрак от висок клас на Happy Dreams,
        дизайнерски нощни шкафчета и красива стояща лампа, както и голям поръчков гардероб до тавана. Прозорците са
        покрити със от сет тънки и дебели "black out" завеси, които гарантират абсолютно затъмняване на помещението.
        Плосък телевизор Samsung е инсталиран на стената.</p>

      <p>Детската спалня също разполага с двойно легло, но с размер 164х200 см, и също с матрак от висок клас на Happy
        Dreams, дизайнерски нощни шкафчета. Голям гардероб по поръчка е монтиран до тавана. Телевизор Samsung е
        инсталиран на стената.</p>

      <p>Коридорът разполага с голям шкаф за обувки, простиращ се до тавана, голямо огледало със закачалки и красива
        дървена пейка.</p>

      <p>Терасата е достатъчно просторна и разполага със столчета и масичка от ратан.</p>

      <p>Настилките във всички помещения са от естествен камък — мрамор, а банята е комбинация от мрамор Розалия, гранит
        Тан Браун и декоративна мазилка по интериорен проект. Подовата настилка на балкона е от плочки от естествена
        глина – Клинкер. Стените са предварително изшкурени и грундирани, след което са боядисани в светъл нюанс охра, с
        качествена латексова боя. Жилището разполага и с блиндирана входна врата в съответствие с всички жилища в
        резиденцията. Всички врати в жилището са от качествен MDF.</p>

      <p>При строителството на сградата са използвани висок клас материали, в това число всички външни и преградни стени
        са зидани с тухли Wienerberger, с висока шумоизолираност, с машинно поставена мазилка и гладка шпакловка. Всички
        стени в апартамента са тухлени - масивни, не е използван гипсокартон, освен на местата с ревизионни отвори.
        Прозорците на всички апартаменти в сградата са от от алуминиева Elvial дограма от реномирания производител
        Kristian Neiko, с подпрозоречни первази от естествен камък. Санитарията в банята е Grohe (вградена структура,
        батерии и душ). Тоалетна чиния и умивалник - Roca/Ideal Standard, електрически бойлер Ariston за топла вода,
        бързозагряващ, с вместимост 120 л., електрически вентилатор, свързан към отдушник. Зоната за къпане в банята
        разполага със стъклена преграда. Инсталирани са аксесоари в банята.</p>

      <p>
        Всяка стая на апартамента е оборудвана с висок клас инверторни климатици от реномираната марка Daikin, работещи
        в режим охлаждане през лятото и отопление през зимата (до минус 20 градуса).
      </p>

      <p>Всяко помещение разполага с изводи за Интернет и кабелна телевизия, към които са включени телевизорите и рутер
        за безжичен Интернет.</p>

      <p class='mb-0'>За сградата</p>
      <p>
        Резиденция Belle Époque в Лозенец, е една от най-красивите и елегантни жилищни сгради по българското Черноморие.
        Изградена в класически френски стил, с множество орнаменти по фасадата, нейният дизайн-проект е вдъхновен от
        архитектурата на емблематичните курорти по Лазурния бряг Ница, Кан и Сен Тропе. Идеята за построяването й е
        повлияна от забележителната елегантност и насладата от живота, характерни за края на 18-ти и началото на 19-ти
        век. "Belle Époque" или "Xубавото време" е период на разцвет на изкуствата, изпълнен с красота, безгрижие и
        разкош, който оставя завинаги носталгията по една прекрасна утопична хармония.
      </p>

      <p>
        Всеки орнамент на сградата, всеки малък детайл допринася за пълната хармония на облика й. Пищните корнизи,
        изящно извитите парапети от ковано желязо и перлената белота в съчетание с богато озеленяване пренасят
        обитателите в онзи изгубен рай на "Хубавото време", който съчетава романтика и блясък, лукс и безгрижие,
        изисканост и красота.
      </p>

      <p>
        Belle Époque Beach Residence представлява жилищна сграда на четири етажа с разгъната застроена площ 2236 кв.м. и
        само 36 апартамента, разпределени в 3 тела. В периметъра на сградата са разположение и 14 открити паркоместа.
        Разположена е на оградена територия с контролиран достъп само за собствениците и гости на резиденцията.
        Завършена през лятото на 2016 г., Резиденцията заема първа морска линия до красивия централен пясъчен плаж на
        Лозенец, недалеч от живописния скалист нос Амбелиц. В съседство се намират плажните заведения, ресторант Тарама
        и пиано бийч бар Camino. Централният плаж на Лозенец е един от 5-те плажа, намиращи се в пешеходна близост.
        Недалеч от резиденцията се намира малкият миден плаж Меча дупка, култовият плаж Корал, както и плажове Hacienda
        Beach и Oasis. Центърът на курорта Лозенец с неговите емблематични барове и ресторанти се намира само на 10
        минути пеша и до него се стига лесно по самия плаж или по плажната алея.
      </p>

      <p>
        Екстрите и удобствата в сградата включват голям басейн със зона за деца, зона с шезлонги и чадъри, рецепция с
        рецепционист през летните месеци, нощна охрана целогодишно, представително фоайе/лоби зона с луксозен интериор и
        мебели, паркинг, контролиран достъп, озеленена градина с различни растения, в това число палми.</p>







    <div class="overlay-border-bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
  <a role="button" class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#offer-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
  </a>

</div>
</div>
```

and sCSS:

```
offer-icon {
  height: 2.7rem;
}

#offer-module #offer-collapse.collapse:not(.show) {
  height: 450px !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
#offer-module #offer-collapse.collapsing {
  height: 450px !important;
}
#offer-module a.collapsed:after {
  content: "\f078";
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
  color: $dark;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
#offer-module a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 50%;
}

#offer-module a:not(.collapsed):after {
  content: "\f077";
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
  color: $dark;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
#offer-collapse.collapse:not(.show) {
  position: relative;
  & .overlay-border-bottom {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;

    width: 100%;
    height: 32px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.63);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.63) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 99%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.63)), color-stop(99%, rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255,255,255,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.63) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 99%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.63) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 99%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.63) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 99%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0.63) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 99%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=0 );
  }
}



.second-col-offer{
  float: right;
  width: 50vw;
}

.clearfix::before, .clearfix::after {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}
.clearfix::after {
  clear: both;
}
```